# Azure - Uninstall IaaSDiagnostics Extension after manually deleting Storage account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I need to uninstall the IaaSDiagnostics Extension for my VM.

However I have manually deleted the diagnostic storage account and now when I try to uninstall the diagnostic extension I get an error saying:

> Provisioning state Provisioning failed.
>
> StorageAccount 'xxxxxdiag160' associated with VM 'xxxxxx' for boot
> diagnostics encountered an error. Please look at the error code for
> more information about the error.. StorageAccountNotFound
>
> Provisioning state error code ProvisioningState/failed/StorageAccountNotFound

How can I delete the IaaSDiagnostics Extension now with the Storage Account associated already deleted?

Comment: Try to use azure powershell `Remove-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <ExtensionName> -VMName <VMName>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Azure has some background processor that will clean up orphan extensions. The IaaSDiagnostics extension is gone automatically after a few hours.